# WIX 3.8 installer: Add files to a pre-existing folder

Tags: wix

How would I install files directly into a pre-existing folder on the user's computer? All documentation I read only explains creating a custom INSTALLDIR.

Eg. c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\ExampleFolderA\ExampleFolderB\InstalledFile.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first define the directory structure:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="ExampleFolderAId" Name="ExampleFolderA">
      <Directory Id="ExampleFolderBId" Name="ExampleFolderB" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Note that the definition above does NOT create directories when the installation runs. In order for the directories to be actually "created" you have to either place files there (using `Component` elements), or explicitly state that the directory is empty.

Something like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ExampleFolderAId">
  <Component Id="SampleComponent" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
    <File Id="SampleFile" Source="C:\readme.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

or

```
<DirectoryRef Id="ExampleFolderBId">
  <Component Id="EmptyFolderComponent" Guid="GUID-GOES-HERE">
    <CreateFolder />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Hope you get the idea.