# WIX v3.11.2 - Install to existing folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to create an .msi installer using the WIX toolset. The installer is meant to install an addon for a piece of software. In order for this to work, the files must be installed to the respective folder of the software in the AppData folder (e.g. ../AppData/Roaming/SoftwareName/Addins/AddinName). How is it possible to set the install folder to that path so that it works for all machines? Also, it would be great if the installer could run a check and find whether the path exists and proceed to the installation if yes or cancel the installation if not. Is this something that can be achieved with the wix toolset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012746/wix-3-8-installer-add-files-to-a-pre-existing-folder) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Wix has the ability to do various searches including the following:

1. Directory
2. File
3. Component
4. Registry
5. Ini files

You can use *DirectorySearch* to search for a folder either in a predefined location or everywhere:

Absolute path search:

```
<Property Id=”NPP_Path”>
    <DirectorySearch Path=”C:\Program Files\Notepad++”
                 Depth=”0”
                 AssignToProperty=”yes”
                 Id=”nppFolderSearch” />
</Property>
```

Comprehensive search:

```
<Property Id=”NPP_Path”>
    <DirectorySearch Path=”Notepad++”
                 Depth=”5”
                 AssignToProperty=”yes”
                 Id=”nppFolderSearch” />
</Property>
```

The latter search is better; it will search for folder Notepad++ by drilling down to 5 subfolders in all available drives and directories. However, this will cause a waiting time. Worse, an error will be thrown while searching through hidden, restricted junction points such as C:\Documents and Settings.
In these cases, nesting `DirectorySearch` elements inside one another to tell Windows Installer where to search is a better solution:

```
<Property Id=”NPP_Path”>
    <DirectorySearch Path=”[ProgramFilesFolder]”
                 Depth=”0”
                 AssignToProperty=”no”
                 Id=”ProgramFilesFolderSearch” >
            <DirectorySearch Path=”Notepad++”
                             Depth=”5”
                              AssignToProperty=”yes”
                                  Id=”nppFolderSearch” />
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

The last example searches the Program Files folder, does *not* assign its result to the parent property, then searches Notepad++ folder inside the result of the outer search.

As an example, three DirectorySearch could be nested to find the “Plugins” folder of notepad++.

“Path” attribute could accept:

- WiX properties
- Windows shares (\myshare\myFolder)
- relative paths
- absolute paths
- folder names
- environmental variables in the form of Wix preprocessor syntax `($(env.ALLUSERSPROFILE))`

If the installer cannot find the path set in the parent element, it will skip it and use the default - every attached drive’s root directory.
Each `DirectorySearch` element must get its unique ID; Windows Installer uses these Id attributes to tie all of the elements together into one cohesive search.